# Angular - Decorate Service to Get Multiple Instances

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an `eventService` which will be used across several modules under one `ngApp`. It has the standard usage:

```
eventService.on('eventName');
```

The thing is, I want to decorate the `on` function, in order to prefix the `eventName` with some id that is unique to the module that's using it.

I thought about using a decorator inside each module's config phase, like this:

```
// App
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['eventServiceModule']);
myApp.config(function($provide, eventServiceProvider) {
    $provide.decorator('eventService', eventServiceProvider.decorateWithId(20));
});

// Decorator function (inside eventService)
decorateWithId: (moduleId) => {
    return ['$delegate',function ($delegate) {
           const originalOn = $delegate.on;
           const newEventing = {};

           newEventing.on = function(event) {
                arguments[0] = `${moduleId}_` + event;
                originalOn.apply($delegate, arguments);
           };

           return Object.assign(newEventing, $delegate);
        }
    ];
}
```

But apparently each decorator gets the new decorator object, instead of a new object with the unique id as I hoped.

Any way to fix this, or a new approach to achieve this goal?